# Rerun all VBA function when worksheet opens

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel macro file (.XLSM) with multiple sheets in it.
In the first sheet in every row are some functions defined.

Example:
Cell `A2` is

```
=checkSomething(A2)
```

which puts an `X` in the cell if the conditions are true and an empty string otherwise.

The `checkSomething` function checks cells in other worksheets.

When I change the data in the other worksheets and come back to the first sheet then the functions do not run again. The `X` is not recalculated. How to do that?

Comment: [Application.Calculate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculate)

Comment: I tried it: `Worksheets(1).Calculate` in the `Worksheet_Activate` sub. It gets called but the functions do not get called again. Not even when I close Excel and open it again.

Comment: Do you use `Applicaiton.Volatile` in your `checkSomething` function? I think, it would be good to edit your question and post the function code...

Comment: Create a new Sub and write 'Debug.Print Application.Calculation:Debug.Print Application.EnableEvents'. If the result in the Immediate window isn't -4105 and True, you know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try including the following in the workbook code area:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
End Sub
```